# How to add new pair with Map<DateTime, List<Event>> (Event is a random class)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a `Map<DateTime, List<Event>>` (Event is a random class). Every time I add a new pair, the key (DateTime) is correctly added, but the list is replaced in all keys. Any help? Any Ideas?

Here my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Event event1 = Event("Test Code", "Company");
  Event event2 = Event("Play Game", "Home");
  Event event3 = Event("Learn", "School");
  List<Event> list1 =[];
  List<Event> list2 =[];
  List<Event> list3 =[];
  List<DateTime> listDateTime =[];
  Map<DateTime,List<Event>> mapT = new Map<DateTime,List<Event>>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
            test();
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  void test(){
    for(int i = 1; i<3;i++){
      list3.clear();
      for(int j = 0; j<i;j++){
        list3.add(Event("Test $j", "School"));
      }
      mapT[DateTime(2020, i , 3)]= list3;
      print(mapT.toString());
    }

  }

}
class Event{
  String name;
  String location;

  Event(this.name, this.location);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Event{name: $name, location: $location}';
  }
}
```

Result:

```
I/flutter (19519): {2020-01-03 00:00:00.000: [Event{name: Test 0, location: School}]}
I/flutter (19519): {2020-01-03 00:00:00.000: [Event{name: Test 0, location: School}, Event{name: Test 1, location: School}], 2020-02-03 00:00:00.000: [Event{name: Test 0, location: School}, Event{name: Test 1, location: School}]}
```

Why in 2nd loop key *2020-01-03 00:00:00.000* be updated! I don't want it to update?

Comment: how are you adding a new pair to your map? Would suggest you share the code as well

Comment: `(map[dateTime] ??= <Event>[]).add(event)`

Comment: please check below thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**
So after your code update: the reason **mapT** is updating the value for all keys is because you are storing the variable **list3** (not the data inside list3)as a value for your keys in **mapT**

So using the same example below, you can test this case:

```
List<int> a = new List();
var test = Map<String, List<int>>();
a.add(1);
test["one"]= a;
print(test); // prints {one: [1]}
a.add(2);
test["two"]= a;
print (test); //prints {one: [1, 2], two: [1, 2]}
```

So in your specific case change your code like this:

```
 for(int i = 1; i<3;i++){
  list3.clear();
  for(int j = 0; j<i;j++){

    list3.add(Event("Test $j", "School"));
  }


  mapT[DateTime(2020, i , 3)] = List.from(list3); //this will create a new list, copy the value from list3 and add to mapT

  print(mapT);
}
```

**Generic Answer:**
You haven't added any code so not sure what/where your problem is; but just for reference here is how to update values in a map:

```
var test = Map<String, int>();
test["one"]= 1;
test["two"]= 2;
print (test); // prints {one:1, two:2}
test.putIfAbsent("three",() => 56);  
print(test); // prints {one:1, two:2, three: 56}
```